# How can I use TOctree2::FindNearbyElements to find static meshes that are near the target Static Mesh?

Tags: unreal-4, unreal-5, octree

I successfully added all the static meshes to their nodes inside an Octree. But I can't seem to find the nearby elements.

When setting up a breakpoint at
`UStaticMeshComponent* MeshComponent = OctreeElement.SubjectStaticMesh;`
it says `SubjectStaticMesh` is a NULL.

What could I be doing wrong? Could something be wrong with my syntax?

```
USTRUCT(BlueprintType, Blueprintable)
struct FOctreeElement
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category="Octree Element Struct")
    UStaticMeshComponent* SubjectStaticMesh = nullptr;
    
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Octree Element Struct")
    FBoxSphereBounds BoxSphereBounds;
 
    FOctreeElement()
    {
        BoxSphereBounds = FBoxSphereBounds(FVector(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), FVector(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), 1.0f);
    }
    FOctreeElement(UStaticMeshComponent* InMeshComponent, FBoxSphereBounds InBoxSphereBounds)
    {
        BoxSphereBounds = FBoxSphereBounds(FVector(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), FVector(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), 1.0f);
    }
};
```

```
TArray<UStaticMeshComponent*> AllChildMeshComponents;
GetComponents<UStaticMeshComponent*>(AllChildMeshComponents);
TArray<UStaticMeshComponent*> ChildMeshComponentsToConsider;

for (UStaticMeshComponent* StaticMeshComp : StaticMeshComponents)
{
    FVector MeshPosition = StaticMeshComp->GetComponentLocation();

    // Call FindNearbyElements and pass the iterate bounds function
    OctreeData->FindNearbyElements(MeshPosition, [&ChildMeshComponentsToConsider](const FOctreeElement& OctreeElement){
        UStaticMeshComponent* MeshComponent = OctreeElement.SubjectStaticMesh;
        if (MeshComponent){
            ChildMeshComponentsToConsider.Add(MeshComponent);
        }
    });
}

for(int32 i = 0; i < ChildMeshComponentsToConsider.Num(); i++) {
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("%s"), *ChildMeshComponentsToConsider[i]->GetName())
}
```